# vertical figure arrangement in newspaper layout

Tags: newspaper

I am using the layout provided in overleaf for newspaper format (I attach the code below).

For some reason, I am not able to put two figures, one above the other. In the example below, I will like to put, say, the two atoms images one on top of the other, both with the same column width. How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{newspaper}

\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

\SetPaperName{Committee Times:}

%% The name used in the running header after
%% the first page
\SetHeaderName{Committee Times}

%% and also...
\SetPaperLocation{Washington DC}
\SetPaperSlogan{``All the News I Feel Like Printing.''}
\SetPaperPrice{Zero Dollars}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{picinpar}

%% In overleaf this package is newspaper-mod!!!!!
\usepackage{newspaper}
%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{3}

\byline{Geek Designs New \LaTeX{} Package}{Matthew Allen}

The package is basically a redefinition of the \verb+\maketitle+ command.  The model was the New York Times---hopefully I haven't violated any copyright laws.  I also had to redefine the plain pagestyle.  It kept me busy for a few nights after work.  The rest is packages other people have written.      

\begin{window}[3,l,\includegraphics[width=1.0in]{atom.jpg},\centerline{The Atom}] The \verb+multicol+ package allows using multiple columns without starting a new page.  Using floats is not possible in a columns environment, however with the \verb+picinpar+ package, I can set a picture inside a block of text---just like you one you see here.  Isn't \LaTeX{} cool?
And now we're just filling more space, and yet more space.  
\end{window}
\closearticle


\headline{Another Headline}
This is just an example to fill up some space, but as long as I have your attention, I'll give some newspaper advice.

I suppose we could also show how an equation is type set:
\begin{displaymath}
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{displaymath}
and there you have it.  

\lipsum[1-4]

\closearticle

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the two images in one `minipage`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{newspaper}

\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{1}

\SetPaperName{Committee Times:}

%% The name used in the running header after
%% the first page
\SetHeaderName{Committee Times}

%% and also...
\SetPaperLocation{Washington DC}
\SetPaperSlogan{``All the News I Feel Like Printing.''}
\SetPaperPrice{Zero Dollars}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{picinpar}

%% In overleaf this package is newspaper-mod!!!!!
\usepackage{newspaper}
%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        
        \byline{Geek Designs New \LaTeX{} Package}{Matthew Allen}
        
        The package is basically a redefinition of the \verb+\maketitle+ command.  The model was the New York Times---hopefully I haven't violated any copyright laws.  I also had to redefine the plain pagestyle.  It kept me busy for a few nights after work.  The rest is packages other people have written.      
        
        \begin{window}[2,l,\begin{minipage}{1in}\includegraphics[width=1.0in]{example-image-a} \smallskip \\ \includegraphics[width=1.0in]{example-image-b}\end{minipage},\centerline{Two Atoms}] The \verb+multicol+ package allows using multiple columns without starting a new page.  Using floats is not possible in a columns environment, however with the \verb+picinpar+ package, I can set a picture inside a block of text---just like you one you see here.  Isn't \LaTeX{} cool?
            And now we're just filling more space, and yet more space.  
        \end{window}
    
        \closearticle       
        
        \headline{Another Headline}
        This is just an example to fill up some space, but as long as I have your attention, I'll give some newspaper advice.
        
        I suppose we could also show how an equation is type set:
        \begin{displaymath}
            x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
        \end{displaymath}
        and there you have it.  
        
        \lipsum[1-4]
            
        \closearticle
        
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow up question

To use the full width of the column for the two images replace the `\begin{window} ... \end{window}` with a minipage like

```
The package is basically a redefinition of the \verb+\maketitle+ command.  The model was the New York Times---hopefully I haven't violated any copyright laws.  I also had to redefine the plain pagestyle.  It kept me busy for a few nights after work.  The rest is packages other people have written.      

\smallskip \noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0in]{example-image-a} \vspace{10pt}
    
    \includegraphics[width=1.0in]{example-image-b}
    
    Two Atoms
\end{minipage}

The \verb+multicol+ package allows using multiple columns without starting a new page.  Using floats is not possible in a columns environment, however with the \verb+picinpar+ package, I can set a picture inside a block of text---just like you one you see here.  Isn't \LaTeX{} cool?
    And now we're just filling more space, and yet more space.
```

[image: c]

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I would not like to open a new thread but... is there a way to keep only the figure legend and get rid of the text beside the images? For some reason if I erase the text starting with "The multicol..." then the images are also erased.

Comment: @user2820579 Thank you for your feedback! Please see the updated answer.